# Array values not changing?

Tags: c#

For some reason, this doesn't edit the size of the array inputted into it, and the data isn't added to the array inputted.

```
    public static void RandomizeArray(int[] array)
    {
        int intRead;
        int intReadSeed;
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("How many ints do you want to randomly generated?");
        intRead = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        array = new int[intRead];
        Console.WriteLine("What's the maximum value of the randomly generated ints?");
        intReadSeed = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < intRead; i++)
        {
            array[i] = (randomNum.Next(intReadSeed));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Randomization Complete.\n");
    }
```

Comment: Note: You should use `randomNum.Next(intReadSeed + 1)`, otherwise the maximum value will be one less than `intReadSeed`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass array to this method, you pass it by value - that is, you make a brand new variable that ALSO points to the same object. If you edit the variable `array` in your method to point to a new array, it doesn't also make the other variable point to your new array - it still points to the old array. So when you return you haven't done any edits to the `array` that was passed in.

To fix this, `return array;` at the end of the method, and change the signature from `void` to `int[]`. Or you can do `out int[] array` as the parameter, so you pass by reference and edit over it.

Comment: In this case, the incoming array isn't used at all, so if the first fix is chosen, also remove the parameter, and if the second fix is used, write `out` instead of `ref`, as Romoku suggests in his answer.

Comment: In this case, which would be more efficient to do out int[] array or just simply return a value instead?

Comment: @user1067625 They're equally efficient, but most methods do `return` instead of `out`. `out` is usually only used in the case of 'returning' more than one thing from the method.

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix declare the parameter as `out`.

```
public static void RandomizeArray(out int[] array)
{
    int intRead;
    int intReadSeed;
    Random randomNum = new Random();

    Console.WriteLine("How many ints do you want to randomly generated?");

    intRead = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    array = new int[intRead];

    Console.WriteLine("What's the maximum value of the randomly generated ints?");
    intReadSeed = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < intRead; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (randomNum.Next(intReadSeed));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Randomization Complete.\n");
}
```

That way you can call it:

```
int[] array;

RandomizeArray(out array);
```

However, it would probably be better to simply return an array.

```
public static int[] GenerateRandomizedArray()
{
    int intRead;
    int intReadSeed;
    Random randomNum = new Random();

    Console.WriteLine("How many ints do you want to randomly generated?");
    intRead = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    var array = new int[intRead];

    Console.WriteLine("What's the maximum value of the randomly generated ints?");
    intReadSeed = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < intRead; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (randomNum.Next(intReadSeed));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Randomization Complete.\n");

    return array;
}
```